Spring Boot + Hibernate - unnecessary update after saving
I have a very weird situation. I have two objects to save in loop. There is invoked service method with new transaction. After first iteration the first row is updated. After second and last iteration the second row is updated BUT the first row is not updated!
In my for loop I have:
public List<Event> changeSth(

for (TimeWindow updatedTimeWindow : updatedTimeWindows) {
            try {
                timeWindowAndAnnouncementEvents.addAll(facade.updateTimeWindow(updatedTimeWindow, modifyingCompany));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                
            }
        }

and:
@Service
public class Facade {
 @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public List<Event> updateSth(
...
service.updateRoute(updatedTimeWindow);
...

And:
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void updateRoute(TimeWindow timeWindow) {
        Optional<Route> oldRoute = routeRepository.findRouteById(timeWindow.getRoute().getId());
        oldRoute.ifPresent(route -> {
            updateSpots(timeWindow, route); // route object is updated and should be saved after transaction ends up
        });
    }

I have 2 objects in updatedTimeWindows, 2 iterations in for loop. After first iteration everything is OK, data are updated in the first row of table Spot. But after second iteration not only the second row is updated but there is update query that sets the old data to my first row of my table. Why?
